# How to set some values with an interval in a vector to be another vector

Tags: python

I have a vector with size, for example,  `(1,16)` which is  `x = [1,2,3,4,.....16]` and another vector `y = [1,2,3,4]` whose size is`( 1,4)`

I want to set the values in the vector x with interval 4 to be the vector y. it means it will be like that `x(1:4:16) = y` ; In python, how can I do that?

The expected output is to be `x = [1 2 3 4 2 6 7 8 3 10 11 12 4 14 15 16]`.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @U12-Forward I added the expected output, it's to replace the values in vector x whose index are 1 : 4 : end with the vector y.

Comment: Posted an answer, please accept and upvote if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using slice assignment:

```
x[::len(y)] = y
```

And now:

```
print(x)
```

Will give:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 3, 10, 11, 12, 4, 14, 15, 16]
```